# DISTINCT Query Error When Using Selected FeedOptions

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

The following query:

•   SELECT DISTINCT c.AccountId FROM c WHERE c._irUnsearchable = false ORDER by c.AccountId

When issued against Cosmos DB using SQL document client (version 2.6.0) with the following options:

- FeedOptions.EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true
- FeedOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1
- FeedOptions.MaxBufferedItemCount = [default value]

Results in the error:

*System.ArgumentException: Distict query requires a matching order by in order to return a continuation token.
If you would like to serve this query through continuation tokens, then please rewrite the query in the form 'SELECT DISTINCT VALUE c.blah FROM c ORDER BY c.blah' and please make sure that there is a range index on 'c.blah'.*

This problem is seen against the Cosmos DB emulator as well as against the service. Note that the same query succeeds when issued against the emulator from the data explorer (Not specifying FeedOptions).

Do you have any idea as to how we can resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you try using a composite index and see if that resolves this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-query-performance#queries-with-both-a-filter-and-an-order-by-clause

Comment: Checked on this and I believe the fix here is to include c._irUnsearchable in the SELECT. Please try and let me know if this fixes it. thanks.

Comment: Mark, thanks for looking into this. I will try your suggestion later this week and let you know how it works out.

Comment: Mark, I still see the same error after following your suggestion (SELECT DISTINCT c.AccountId, c._irUnsearchable FROM c WHERE c._irUnsearchable = false ORDER by c.AccounttId). One thing that I cannot understand is that I do not encounter the error when using the explorer even when setting the same feed options. Could this be related to the client version? Thanks.

Comment: You need the VALUE keyword in your query. Try this.
SELECT DISTINCT VALUE c.AccountId FROM c WHERE c._irUnsearchable = false ORDER by c.AccountId